# Python numpy data pointer addresses change without modification

Tags: python, pointers, numpy

**EDIT**

After some more fiddling around, I've so far isolated the following states:

1. A **1D array** gives *two* different addresses when entering variable directly, and only *one* when using `print()`
2. A **2D array** (or **matrix**) gives *three* different addresses when entering variable directly, and *two* when using `print()`
3. A **3D array** gives *two* different address when entering variable directly, and only *one* when using `print()` (apparently the same as with the **1D array**)

Like so:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3], dtype="int32")

>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4048>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4048>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4048>

>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>
>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>
>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>
>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>
>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e85e4110>


>>> d = numpy.array([[1,2,3]], dtype="int32")

>>> d.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>

>>> print(d.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> print(d.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> print(d.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> print(d.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> print(d.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>


>>> b = numpy.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype="int32")

>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>
>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>

>>> print(b.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>
>>> print(b.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> print(b.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>
>>> print(b.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> print(b.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>


>>> c = numpy.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype="int32")

>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>
>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>
>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> c.data
<memory at 0x7f02e863aac8>

>>> print(c.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> print(c.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> print(c.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>
>>> print(c.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863a9e8>
>>> print(c.data)
<memory at 0x7f02e863ae48>


>>> e = numpy.array([[[0,1],[2,3]],[[4,5],[6,7]]], dtype="int32")

>>> e.data
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1048>
>>> e.data
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1140>
>>> e.data
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1048>
>>> e.data
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1140>
>>> e.data
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1048>


>>> print(e.data)
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1048>
>>> print(e.data)
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1048>
>>> print(e.data)
<memory at 0x7f8ca0fe1048>
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I was under the impression that merely entering a variable along in the python console with echo a string simply describing the value (and type) of it. It formats in a different manner than print(), but I assumed the values they both returned would be the same.

When I try to output the address of the data pointer object of a numpy object, just entering the variable gives me different value every other time, while print() gives the same value.

That suggests that the difference in the two operations aren't just how the output is formatted, but also where they get their information from. But what exactly do these additional differences consist of?

```
>>> a = numpy.array([0,1,2])

>>> a
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> print(a)
[0 1 2]

>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7ff25120c110>
>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7ff25120c110>
>>> print(a.data)
<memory at 0x7ff25120c110>

>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7ff25120c110>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7ff253099818>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7ff25120c110>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7ff253099818>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7ff25120c110>
```

Comment: The same thing happens on my machine with Python 3.5. Very odd, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The `memoryview` returned by `a.data` seems to alternate between two (or more) views. If you store a given instance of `a.data`, you get consistent output:

```
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88ea1f828>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98c4a8>
>>> t = a.data
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98ce48>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98c3c8>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98c4a8>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98ce48>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98c3c8>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fb88e98c4a8>
>>> t
<memory at 0x7fb88ea1f828>
>>> t
<memory at 0x7fb88ea1f828>
>>> t
<memory at 0x7fb88ea1f828>
```

Note that there are 3 addresses rotating in the above example; I'm pretty sure this is all an implementation detail. I would guess that some caching is involved, implying that a new view is not actually generated each time you access `a.data`.

You can also make certain that you are looking at separate view objects:

```
>>> id(a.data)
140430643088968
>>> id(a.data)
140430643086280
>>> id(a.data)
140430643088968
>>> id(a.data)
140430643086280
```

So most of the confusion probably comes from the fact that the attribute notation of `a.data` would suggest that it's a fixed object we're talking about, while this is not the case.

Comment: Sounds plausible. But I'm curious about the implementation detail; what advantage or function does this actually serve?

Comment: @lash I'm pretty clueless when it comes to python implementation, so I can only guess. My take is that it's the other way around: `a.data` is supposed to generate a new view for you each time, but the interpreter is smart enough to cache some of these views, so that it doesn't give you a new one each time. So the advantage would not be "why are there a few addresses alternating?", but more like "why are there *only* a few addresses alternating?". But as I said, this is just a guess:) I'm also curious.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html)

> ndarray.data
>
> Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data.

Which should just be a `memoryview` of the data.

*Edit, trying to be clearer*:

In my case, a *1-D* array gives new values every time - it doesn't cycle between two values only:

```
In [196]: a = numpy.array([0, 1, 2])

In [197]: a.data
Out[197]: <read-write buffer for 0x7f7de5934f80, size 24, offset 0 at 0x7f7de594d4b0>

In [198]: a.data
Out[198]: <read-write buffer for 0x7f7de5934f80, size 24, offset 0 at 0x7f7de594df70>

In [199]: a.data
Out[199]: <read-write buffer for 0x7f7de5934f80, size 24, offset 0 at 0x7f7de594d570>

In [200]: a.data
Out[200]: <read-write buffer for 0x7f7de5934f80, size 24, offset 0 at 0x7f7de594d870>
```

I think the behaviour is not peculiar to numpy only. See what happens with a `buffer`:

```
In [222]: a = ('123' * 999)

In [223]: buffer(a)
Out[223]: <read-only buffer for 0x7f7de003cbd0, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7f7de5955170>

In [224]: buffer(a)
Out[224]: <read-only buffer for 0x7f7de003cbd0, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7f7de594ddb0>

In [225]: buffer(a)
Out[225]: <read-only buffer for 0x7f7de003cbd0, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7f7de597a5b0>

In [226]: buffer(a)
Out[226]: <read-only buffer for 0x7f7de003cbd0, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7f7de594de70>
```

In the case of `Buffer`, the doc says (emphasis mine):

> buffer(object[, offset[, size]])
>
> The object argument must be an object that supports the buffer call interface (such as strings, arrays, and buffers). *A new buffer object will be created which references the object argument*.

So I guess we should expect the address memory to change. However, back to the original question, it seems that caching happens and I concur with you both, that it must be down to some sort of optimisation. Unfortunately, why and in which cases the caching happens, I cannot find out in the Python code base.

Comment: Firstly, it's a `matrix`. Secondly, this doesn't really explain the "every other call" thing. I guess it might be some caching involved?

Comment: Whoa, my bad. First time it was an array, the second time a matrix. The cases get different results. Also, matrices of different sizes get different results. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah, don't worry. I don't think the behaviour depends on the type of data. I'll try and be clearer in the post.

Comment: @Jir I agree, I was mostly being pedantic. Although if you look at the latest edit on the question, there's some weird black magic going on depending on the data type. Not that this should be attributed much importance, in my opinion:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, it's definitely weird, but not sure how it is dependent on the type of data (see the results I pasted in my post). Definitely an interesting aspect! :)

Answer (score 0):

In python, `object.attribute` does not necessarily just lookup and retrieve a pre-stored variable. For example, it may instead execute a customisable *function* `object.__getattr__("attribute")` which can return anything at all (and could have arbitrary side-effects) and may even return different values if is invoked multiple times.

Don't confuse the raw memory allocation (where the values of a `numpy.ndarray` are stored) with the address of a `memoryview` object (that only stores metadata relating to a memory allocation).

The actual memory address of the array is given by `ndarray.ctypes.data`. This generates an integer, with the same value each time it is requested. (In cpython it actually generates a different `int` object each time, but this doesn't matter because it generates all of them to have the same value.)

```py
>>> array = numpy.ones((10,10))
>>> address = array.ctypes.data
>>> address2 = array.ctypes.data
>>> address is address2
False
>>> address == address2
True
>>> address, address2, id(address), id(address2)
94626990418400, 94626990418400, 140364094130064, 140364094130224
```

Similarly, invoking `ndarray.data` generates a `memoryview` object, and each time you do this it will be a different, new `memoryview` object (although they will all store identical metadata since they are each describing the same array).

Unfortunately, when you try to print a `memoryview` instance to the console (i.e. when you ask the `memoryview` to generate a string representation of itself), it returns a sentence describing the location where this `memoryview` itself is located and *not* the location that this `memoryview` stores references to. (It presents this number in base 16, whereas python normally presents integers in base 10.)

```py
>>> x = array.data
>>> repr(x), id(x), hex(id(x))
'<memory at 0x7fa90fff3a68>', 140364094585448, '0x7fa90fff3a68'
```

If you simply type `array.data` into a console repeatedly, you will likely see different hex values each time, because you are regenerating new `memoryview` objects (that all describe the same array).

You also may sometimes see cyclical repeats of the same hex values (assuming you do not assign a unique name for each `memoryview` object, either by not assigning a name at all or by reassigning the name to a subsequent object). This is because once an object is no longer needed (i.e. there are no longer any name-handles for your code to refer to that same particular instance of the object again) it is discarded, and the space it formerly occupied becomes freed for new objects to use instead. So if you repeatedly execute `array.data` you may sometimes find that a new `memoryview` object gets constructed at the exact same address where an earlier one had been.